# ffmpeg won't save the file when executed from a php page

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I wrote few lines of codes today to  create an video from an image with ffmpeg.

the command works well directly on my server and the file is saved at the good place, but when running it from PHP, the process goes, but the file won't save for some reason.

Here is the code I use :

```
$ffmpegcmd= "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i /home/mysite/www/forwork/simpletext.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p /home/mysite/www/forwork/movie.avi 2>&1";
exec($ffmpegcmd, $output);  
print_r($output);
```

And here is the answer I get :

```
Array ( [0] => ffmpeg version git-2015-09-06-db18b3d Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers 
[1] => built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) 
[2] => configuration: --prefix=/usr/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/usr/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 
[3] => libavutil 55. 0.100 / 55. 0.100 
[4] => libavcodec 57. 0.100 / 57. 0.100 
[5] => libavformat 57. 0.100 / 57. 0.100 
[6] => libavdevice 57. 0.100 / 57. 0.100 
[7] => libavfilter 6. 0.100 / 6. 0.100 
[8] => libswscale 4. 0.100 / 4. 0.100 
[9] => libswresample 2. 0.100 / 2. 0.100 
[10] => libpostproc 54. 0.100 / 54. 0.100 
[11] => Input #0, image2, from '/home/mysite/www/forwork/simpletext.jpg': 
[12] => Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10414 kb/s 
[13] => Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc 
[14] => /home/mysite/www/forwork/movie.avi: Permission denied )
```

I chmod the forwork directory to 755 but it won't change anything.

help troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Did you do `chmod -R 755 /home/mysite/www/forwork/`? If the file has different permissions that could be an issue. Also remember php runs a different user to you...

Comment: @ScottMcGready yes, did the chmod -R and the problem remains unfortunately

Comment: Which user is apache/PHP running as? Ensure they have permissions to the group that owns `movie.avi` (might not solve your question but a worthwhile thing to check.

Comment: @ScottMcgready Actually after your comment, I deleted the file movie.avi (which was created from the root user) and the script now runs well. So it was actually a problem of permission. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: glad to hear it! for the avoidance of doubt I've summarised my comments below as an answer for any future browsers of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permissions errors can cause quite the headache. Here's a few things you can do to ensure your script has the correct permissions:

- Ensure both the parent folder, and it's contents are readable by doing a `chmod -R 755 /home/mysite/www/forwork/`
- Check the ownership of the file/directory by doing `ls -l`
- Add Apache's user into the group that owns the folder/file (alternatively run `chown -R apacheuser:group /home/mysite/www/forwork` on the parent folder.